# Hibernate IdentifierGenerationException: unrecognized id type : uuid-binary

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi all and thanks for your time. I've run into a little trouble with auto-generating java.util.UUIDs.

Consider the following entity:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="clients")
public class Client {
    @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
    @javax.persistence.Id
    private UUID id;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

When attempting to persist a new instance, I get the following stacktrace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: unrecognized id type : uuid-binary -> java.util.UUID
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:257)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.persist(Unknown Source)
at com.shorecg.artemis.model.repository.impl.jpa.JpaRepository.save(JpaRepository.java:116)
at com.shorecg.artemis.model.repository.impl.jpa.JpaRepository$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1a43e5e0.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:713)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:646)
at com.shorecg.artemis.model.repository.impl.jpa.authn.JpaClientRepository$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e44cf7a.save(<generated>)
at com.shorecg.artemis.server.controllers.Client.postJson(Client.java:71)
at com.shorecg.artemis.server.controllers.Client$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8f5a18aa.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:713)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:646)
at com.shorecg.artemis.server.controllers.Client$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b3bf8521.postJson(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:696)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1568)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1539)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:453)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1044)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I've seen many solutions that involve the use of @GenericGenerator. If the model is supplied by a vendor and cannot be modified, how then may I rectify the situation. I have come across snippets which suggest I might be able to register a default generator through the SessionFactory, but I've yet to determine how.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit:**

I did some digging through the sources indicated by the trace, and I came to this section in org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper:

```
Class clazz = type.getReturnedClass();
if (rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() == 1) {
    if ( clazz == Long.class ) {
        return rs.getLong( 1 );
    }
    else if ( clazz == Integer.class ) {
        return rs.getInt( 1 );
    }
    else if ( clazz == Short.class ) {
        return rs.getShort( 1 );
    }
    else if ( clazz == String.class ) {
        return rs.getString( 1 );
    }
    else if ( clazz == BigInteger.class ) {
        return rs.getBigDecimal( 1 ).setScale( 0, BigDecimal.ROUND_UNNECESSARY ).toBigInteger();
    }
    else if ( clazz == BigDecimal.class ) {
        return rs.getBigDecimal( 1 ).setScale( 0, BigDecimal.ROUND_UNNECESSARY );
    }
    else {
        throw new IdentifierGenerationException(
            "unrecognized id type : " + type.getName() + " -> " + clazz.getName()
        );
    }
}
```

At a glance, unless I'm missing something higher up in the chain, there seems to be no way of returning anything other than a primitive as a generated id.

**Further Edit:**

The column type in the database was incorrect. Fixing it did not rectify the problem. I did however notice that if I generate the UUID myself using java.util.UUID.randomUUID that Hibernate persists the ID correctly. At this point I'm marching forward with application-generated UUIDs, but I'd like to find out why I've been having this problem. Alternatively, I'm willing to entertain reasons why I shouldn't bother with letting Hibernate generate the uuids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also declare a generator in a `package-info.java` file and then use it via the `@GeneratedValue` annotation on the id field.

package-info.java:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
package org.leanhis.patientmanagement;
```

PatientEntity.java:

```
public class PatientEntity implements Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @Column
    private UUID id;
```

Answer (score 0):

So the clue lies a few lines above the org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper snippet you quoted:

```
if ( ResultSetIdentifierConsumer.class.isInstance( type ) ) {
        return ( ( ResultSetIdentifierConsumer ) type ).consumeIdentifier( rs );
    }
```

In your case you could create a custom ID type that implements UserType and ResultSetIdentifierConsumer. See [this tutorial](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-basic-type-using-hibernate-usertype/)

Comment: I'm sorry. Stackoverflow didn't notify me of this. An excellent insight!